# ElectronJS: npm ERR! errno 4294930435

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have this ElectronJS project that I finally managed to build correctly (no errors when building). But when I am trying to start it, I just get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 4294930435
npm ERR! movie-ex-gui@1.0.0 start: `electron dist/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294930435
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the movie-ex-gui@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anoneemo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-22T16_56_16_185Z-debug.log
```

I can't make sense of the [debug.log](https://pastebin.com/7msWV4MN) file either.

But when I try to launch the application with `electron dist/main.js --enable-logging` instead of the npm start script, I get this in the console:
`[16724:0122/180054.390:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(808)] not connected`. I have tried removing the `node_modules` folder, installing again, verifying the cache, restarting the computer and pretty much everything I could dig up on google.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? It launched fine before I had the error when building. Then I got error when building and fixed that by simply adding an exclude to my webpack babel-loader. Then it builds fine, but wont startup at all. The whole project can be found here: [movie-ex](https://github.com/kaizokupuffball/movie-ex/tree/to_class).

Any clues anyone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after upgrading from Electron 8.1.0 to 11.2.0
I narrowed it down to the use of "__dirname" in the "new BrowserWindow" -> "icon" setting.
Whilst commenting that line out clears the bug, a solution needs to be found.

Comment: @Midnight-Coding post that as an answer. That actually worked, to remove the icon line. How did you trace the problem to that line? :o

Edit: 
Since you said that was the problem, I tried adding this to my webpack configuration:

  node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true
  }

That also works, instead of commenting out the line

Comment: Great news. It was a process of elimination by replacing certain sections of the file with the good old console.log("Test"); line. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that I do not use webpack, I received the exact same error after upgrading Electron from v8.1.0 to v11.2.0

My error appeared to originate from the use of the "__dirname" variable when used in the Electron "new BrowserWindow" -> "icon" setting.

As you are using modules, I suspect it may have something to do with the "new BrowserWindow -> webPreferences -> nodeIntegration" and "contextIsolation" scope settings, thus your need to set `__dirname: true` in your "webpack.config.js" file (Ref: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)

PS: I'm not full bottle on the updated Electron "nodeIntegration" and "contextIsolation" settings as I only updated my app this morning for the first time in a long time and learnt of the changed / pending default setting(s) of Electron v12.

More information can be found below:

- [nodeIntegration](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506)
- [contextIsolation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/context-isolation.md)

---

Funnily enough, my original "icon" value was `icon: __dirname + '',`. I had set this early on during development and subsequently forgot to point it to a proper *.ico file later on.

I just created an "icon.ico" file and set the "icon" value accordingly.

`icon: __dirname + '/../../../icons/icon.ico'` This seemed to work.

As an alternative, I also tried the following (with the "icon" line commented out).

`win.setIcon(__dirname + '/../../../icons/icon.ico');` This worked as well.

*Note to self: Refactor to the path -> join function*.

***Important:*** That all said, I currently have set `nodeIntegration: true`. Better sort this out before upgrading to Electron v12.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line inside createWindow function in main.js

```
nodeIntegration: true,
```

Comment: I needed `nodeIntegration` turned on, so could not do that. But the issue is resolved (see answer above).

Comment: If you want to nodeIntegration be on, then you should add ```contextIsolation : false,``` it should be like:
```webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation : false,
    }```