# Exit code 4294930435 in Electron

Tags: electron

When running my Electron app in development (`electron dist/main.js`) I get error `ELIFECYCLE 4294930435` without any error message. It just crashes.

I put some `console.log`s in my `main.js` and it happens after I call `BrowserWindow.loadURL`. I've tried loading a file instead and I've tried loading an absolute URL to github.com and no solution.

What is this exit code and why can't I see any error message? How can I possibly debug this?

I have seen question [ElectronJS: npm ERR! errno 4294930435](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849599/electronjs-npm-err-errno-4294930435/65858821#65858821) but the answer does not help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's somehow related to contextIsolation and the use of __dirname for me. When I comment out where I set the icon using __dirname I no longer receive this error. Haven't found the right way to do this yet.